# mysql to state column location and add comment at same time

Tags: php, mysql

When I added a new column in MySQL, I wrote this:

```
alter TABLE table_name add column `column2` int NOT null DEFAULT 0 after `column1` COMMENT 'this is comment'
```

It seems impossible to add a comment and state the column locate at the same time from [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html). Is there any way to complete them in only one SQL?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `column_name` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'some comments' AFTER `some_column`;
```

Make sure `some_column` already exists

Answer (score 2):

Use following Query to add and comment at the same time

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `column2` int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'this is comment' AFTER `some_column`
```